# arm_data abort failure in case of running my program for the second time and thereafter

Tags: c++

I add my program (load a file and do some computation) into the app of TizenRT on ARTIK053. The program can run successfully in the first time, but the data abort failure will be met when running it second time. The specific error info is as follows:

```
arm_dataabort:
Data abort. PC: 040d25a0 DFAR: 00000011 DFSR: 0000080d
up_assert: Assertion failed at file:armv7-r/arm_dataabort.c line: 111 task: ghsom_test
up_dumpstate: Current sp: 020c3eb0
up_dumpstate: User stack:
up_dumpstate:   base: 020c3fd0
up_dumpstate:   size: 00000fd4
up_dumpstate:   used: 00000220
up_dumpstate: User Stack
up_stackdump: 020c3ea0: 00000003 020c3eb0 040c9638 041d38b8 00000000 040c9644 00000011 0000080
.....
.....
up_taskdump: Idle Task: PID=0 Stack Used=1024 of 1024
up_taskdump: hpwork: PID=1 Stack Used=164 of 2028
up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=2 Stack Used=164 of 2028
up_taskdump: logm: PID=3 Stack Used=300 of 2028
up_taskdump: LWIP_TCP/IP: PID=4 Stack Used=228 of 4068
up_taskdump: tash: PID=6 Stack Used=948 of 4076
up_taskdump: ghsom_test: PID=10 Stack Used=616 of 4052
```

I checked the remaining free RAM space, it is enough for my program. And I added some printing info into my main function to check on which line the error come out. I found that if I commented some lines before the line that the error come out, in the next time I running the program, the error line will move downward some lines. It seems like I released some stack space. So I guess it might be an issue related with the stack size that I can assign to a single proc. Anyone knows the reason, and how to solve the issue? To be mentioned, it only happens for the second time and thereafter I running the program.

Comment: You've stack dump printed - the first easiest thing to do besides printf is to analyze it i.e. with addr2line to check what was called before crash. Also you do computations on files - this means you've defined flash sector for mount point and have data stored there? If so, then there is very small possibility that there is issue with the file.  Generally without code it's only guessing. 
TizenRT is at most nuttx, see [nuttx hardfaults docs](http://nuttx.org/doku.php?id=wiki:howtos:cortexm-hardfault&s[]=analyzing&s[]=hardfaults) for information about hardfaults.

Answer (score 0):

With the stackdump you can almost always figure out where the error originated from. 
Since you have the image file for your build you can do

```
arm-none-eabi-addr2line -f  -p -i -b build/out/bin/tinyara 0xADDR
```

where ADDR would be the addr is one of the relevant addresses in the stack dump. 
You can usually check the "current sp" (stack pointer) but often it points to the arm_dataabort shown in  the failure above.

Then you can check the PC address and also look for addresses in the stack dump (starting from the back of it) that looks like the PC in value. 
In your case it could be addresses like (in that order): 040c9644,  041d38b8, 040c9638
So basically:

```
arm-none-eabi-addr2line -f  -p -i -b build/out/bin/tinyara 0x040c9644
```

notice the 0x in front of the address. 
The command will give you a good indication for where this address is coming from in your binary like:

```
up_idlepm_static at /home/user/tizenrt/os/arch/arm/src/chip/s5j_idle.c:111
(inlined by) up_idle at /home/user/tizenrt/os/arch/arm/src/chip/s5j_idle.c:254
```

if the address is not pointing to code lines then it will look like:

```
??  ??:0
```

hope that helps